# Как использовать mysql в реакт проекте webstorm?

Tags: mysql, node.js, reactjs, webstorm

Я пытаюсь использовать
https://www.npmjs.com/package/mysql
Но я не понимаю, где разместить код

```
var mysql      = require('mysql');
var connection = mysql.createConnection({
  host     : 'localhost',
  user     : 'me',
  password : 'secret',
  database : 'my_db'
});

connection.connect();

connection.query('SELECT 1 + 1 AS solution', function (error, results, fields) {
  if (error) throw error;
  console.log('The solution is: ', results[0].solution);
});

connection.end();
```

У меня возникает ошибка

> TypeError: Net.createConnection is not a function

Я искал способы её исправить и везде написано "надо размещать код в серверном js", я не могу найти "серверный" файл node.js, который создаёт webstorm при создании проекта на реакте.
Раньше я работал с проектами на node.js и создавал серверный файл сам, где его найти здесь - не ясно.

Answer (score 2):

Так делать нельзя. Нельзя подключить `mysql` напрямую в коде ReactJS приложения. Дело в том, что JavaScript, работающий в веб-браузере, не может работать по протоколу MySQL (и при этом он не может создавать необработанные сетевые соединения, которые потребуются для написания реализации в JS).

Вместо этого создайте веб-сервис на выбранном языке программирования, у Вас это JavaScript, работающий на Node.js (например, код, который у вас уже есть + Express.js + немного других зависимостей) и используйте [Axios](https://www.npmjs.com/package/axios) для взаимодействия с веб-сервисом из React приложения.

Полезные ссылки на похожие вопросы:

- [How to connect MySQL database to ReactJS app?](https://stackoverflow.com/a/54325439/5275890)
- [Error in MySQL library for Node.js](https://stackoverflow.com/a/38094604/5275890)